# How to you use your DbContext in an IStringLocalizer implementation?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I am building an ASP.NET Core 2 MVC application and want to use database driven localization of resources. I have created a minimal MVC application that illustrates my problem, the source can be found [here](https://github.com/benm-eras/LocalizationDemo/tree/master/LocalizationDemo), and I will link directly to the objects I am talking about below.

I am using an implementation of the built in `IStringLocalizer` called [`StringResourceLocalizer`](https://github.com/benm-eras/LocalizationDemo/blob/master/LocalizationDemo/Localization/StringResourceLocalizer.cs) which has a dependency on [`IResourceSource`](https://github.com/benm-eras/LocalizationDemo/blob/master/LocalizationDemo/Services/IResourceSource.cs) whose implemetation [`ResourceSource`](https://github.com/benm-eras/LocalizationDemo/blob/master/LocalizationDemo/Services/ResourceSource.cs) is responsible for interacting with my database via my [`DataContext`](https://github.com/benm-eras/LocalizationDemo/blob/master/LocalizationDemo/Data/DataContext.cs).

When starting the application there is a problem with the lifetimes of the various dependencies and I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'LocalizationDemo.Data.DataContext' from singleton 'LocalizationDemo.Services.IResourceSource'.

I understand why I am getting this error, and it makes sense. However I cannot work out how to set up the [lifetime of my dependencies](https://github.com/benm-eras/LocalizationDemo/blob/80c51f551cdbaa50964966c9af50bf7893aa4895/LocalizationDemo/Startup.cs#L29) to get this to work. I have tried several approaches:

1. **Change `IResourceSource` to scoped:** Doesn't work because the `IStringLocalizerFactory` is a singleton
2. **Change `IStringLocalizerFactory` and `IStringLocalizer` to scoped:** results in the following exception

   > InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizerFactory' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.MvcOptions]'.
3. **Replaced `DataContext` [dependency](https://github.com/benm-eras/LocalizationDemo/blob/9fbc2f4e8e65aeaf3c28948ad61685e24c4eeb6c/LocalizationDemo/Services/ResourceSource.cs#L8) with [`DataContextAccessor`](https://github.com/benm-eras/LocalizationDemo/blob/master/LocalizationDemo/Data/DataContextAccessor.cs):** Tried using the service locator (anti)pattern to allow the singleton `ResourceSource` to resolve a scoped `DataContext` instance, but it results in the following exception

   > InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'LocalizationDemo.Data.DataContext' from root provider.

The only approach I have found that "works" is to change my [`DataContext`](https://github.com/benm-eras/LocalizationDemo/blob/80c51f551cdbaa50964966c9af50bf7893aa4895/LocalizationDemo/Startup.cs#L27) to singleton:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(o => o.UseInMemoryDatabase(), ServiceLifetime.Singleton, ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

But I am 99% sure that it is a terrible idea for all requests to be sharing the same context. I thought about using a second context that implements the first that is only used by the localization system, which could then be singleton as per the suggestion [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7636), but the real implementation of `ResourceSource` will be reading **and** *writing* from the database so I really want to avoid singleton!

I have seen [this](https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreLocalization) package that allows you to use Entity Framework for localization, but it uses a singleton `DbContext` and isn't flexible enough for my needs.

Comment: If you google that error you'll find it's a common problem for any middleware project- how to use a scoped service inside a singleton. One option is to register a *factory* method you can use to create new contexts and dispose them yourself. Another one is to inject `IServiceScopeFactory`, create a scope in your code and ask the scope to give you a context instance scoped to your method

Comment: I must have googled the wrong thing because I didn't come across this! Nevermind, [this](https://github.com/benm-eras/LocalizationDemo/blob/6834898fad223fd77ef8bc64bdc78abb3f12b443/LocalizationDemo/Services/ResourceSource.cs#L16) seems to work, is it the correct implementation? If so, feel free to add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Yep - the solution you've implemented in the GitHub repo is the way to go here (using `CreateScope`) - as an aside, you don't need a `using` on the `DbContext`: the `using` on the `Scope` will actually handle that as the `DbContext` is "owned" by the scope.

Comment: Is there any downside to the `using` on the context too? I think it looks neater

Comment: Also, do you need to dispose of the scope if you dispose of the context? I am just thinking that for unit testing it would simplify things if I injected a factory/accessor class that gives you the scoped context and would be easy to mock...

Comment: I would always dispose of something unless I know something else is doing it for me. There's no downside to double-disposing your context given that it implements the dispose pattern and no-ops the second time. It's redundant, which would be enough for me to avoid it but you can do it if you really want to.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if you leave an answer I will accept it, otherwise I will leave one myself to help others with the same question.